# Most efficient way to update live heroku app without typing for each update?

Tags: git, shell

I find myself updating a live Rails application on heroku without needing to speficiy a description for the commit in `git commit -m "description of change"`

**Is there a command or GUI app what would allow me to update an app with one click/line?**

The action would encompass the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "text"
git push heroku master
```

(I realize full well that this might break the best practice approach to TDD.)

Comment: git add . && git commit -m "text" && git push heroku master ?

Comment: `function gp(){git add . && git commit -m "$1" && git push heroku master}`? And then use `gp message`